# Dafny - Call methods inside if statements?

Tags: if-statement, dafny

Like the title says I would like to call on a method that modifies some variables inside an if statement of another method, such as:

```
method A
...
{
    ... // Modifies some variables
}

method B
...
{
    ...
    if(statement){
        A();
    }
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work since Dafny won't allow non ghost methods to be called in such a manner. What would a workaround to this issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, can cast it to a temporary bool variable and then use the bool variable in the expression:

```
    ...
var boolean:bool;
boolean := expression();
is(boolean){
    ...
}
    ...
```